# Custom Report Type, Add Formula Field Issues

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have a lookup on Opportunity that looks up to Lead. I am trying to create a custom report that shows leads with converted information. Now when I go to summary format and click on add formula field, I am not getting the number fields of opportunity like "won" etc for me to build report. I could however see all number fields of Lead. Anything that I am missing here?

Comment: Are these fields available to add to the report as columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i had created custom reports type like you said.Did you create any fields after the report type has been created.You have manually add those fields to the report type section.

But you get all the fields normally Please can you check this one when try to create formula in summary report like.Please check till the end of the list.

For Reference:
[image]